# How can I set up the browser size before my protractor test runs?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I have the following protractor test listed below. It runs fine. But I need to add some code that opens the browser to full screen since my test is sensitive to pixel location of gridster tiles. How can this be done?

```
describe('DragAndDrop Test', function () {
require('protractor');
require('jasmine-expect');


beforeAll(function () {
    context = new Context();
    context.get();
    browser.waitForAngular();
    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();

});

it('should drag and drop Application Experience tile', function () {

    //a = angular.element(document).find('h3')[1]
    //target is where we are dragging the box to.  Box is the Box
    var target = { x: 300, y: 50 };
    var box = element(by.cssContainingText('h3', 'Application Experience'));
    var infoSpot = element(by.cssContainingText('h3', 'Application Experience'));


    //scope is going to hold the scope variables that tell us where the box is located
    //get the standardItems Scope


    box.evaluate('dashboards').then(function(scope) {
        //make sure the box we are using is initially set in column 0 and Row 0
        expect(scope['1'].widgets[0].col).toEqual(0);
        expect(scope['1'].widgets[0].row).toEqual(0);
    });

    //drag and drop the box somewhere else.
    browser.actions().dragAndDrop(box, target).perform();
    browser.waitForAngular();
    browser.driver.sleep(5000);

    //get the updated scope
    box.evaluate('dashboards').then(function(scope) {
        //test to see that the box was actually moved to column 1 and row 0
        expect(scope['1'].widgets[0].col).toEqual(1);
        expect(scope['1'].widgets[0].row).toEqual(0);
    });
});
});

var Context = function () {
this.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    //load the website
    this.get = function () {
        browser.get('http://127.0.0.1:57828/index.html#/dashboard');
    };
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the better practice is to do this in your config.

```
onPrepare: function() {
browser.manage().window().setSize(1600, 1000);
}

or

onPrepare: function() {
browser.manage().window().maximize();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have this line in your `beforeAll` function, which will maximize your browser before any test is run:

```
browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

However, on some operating systems, Chrome browser won't maximize the window horizontally, only vertically. You have two options:

a) Set the width explicitly to some predefined value, e.g:

```
browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(1200, 768);
```

b) Get the screen resolution with a Javascript function and set the window size accordingly.

```
var width = GET_WIDTH;
var height = GET_HEIGHT;    
browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(width, height);
```